# getElementById cuando el id es una consulta php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buenos dias
tengo un checkbox con el id definido por un resultado de una consulta sql en php

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['identificacion']."1"; ?>" onchange="return habilitar()">
```

y estoy tratando de colocarlo en un getElementById para una funcion

```
function habilitar() {
chkb = document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['identificacion']."1"; ?>");
    //chkb = document.getElementById("chk2");
    if (chkb.checked) {
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal pero no me funciona, si utilizo una funcion para ver el id del checkbox si lo muestra sin problema

gracias

Comment: Puedes usar `event.target` dentro de tu función y te regresa el input que estás queriendo buscar con `getElementById`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás intentando realizar, no es posible, aunque entiendo tu intención.

Un fichero o código JavaScript **no** interpreta código PHP, ya que el código php sólo puede ser ejecutado desde el **servidor**. Sí bien es cierto que, **si incluyes** código JS en un script PHP, es posible ir concatenando resultados de PHP con código JS, esto suele usarse cuando queremos generar código JS dinámicamente.

Con la primera respuesta que te ha proporcionado Camilo Vasquez puede servirte, hasta donde podemos comprender, que deseas hacer con ese código. Pero si quieres seguir de esa forma porque desees conseguir otro tipo de efecto podrías hacer lo siguiente:

Para este caso deberías de tener un **input oculto** con un id ya asignado y reconocible (que no sea dinámico como el que intentas recoger), después a éste le añades el valor de tu fila de la consulta. Ahora sí podrás pasarle a tu getElemenById() el valor de este input oculto.

Puedes verlo en este ejemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" id="idCheckbox" value="<?php echo $row['identificacion']."1"; ?>"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['identificacion']."1"; ?>" onchange="return habilitar()">
```

---

```
function habilitar() {
    var idCheckbox = document.getElementById("idCheckbox").value;
    chkb = document.getElementById(idCheckbox);
    //chkb = document.getElementById("chk2");
    if (chkb.checked) {
```

Comment: Superior, es exacto lo que necesitaba. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una solución puede ser enviar el elemento (`this`) como parámetro a tu función, así no tendrías que usar ese `getElementById`

```js
function habilitar(elemento) {
    if (elemento.checked) {
        console.log('chekeado');
    }else{
        console.log('no chekeado');
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="codigo_php" onchange="return habilitar(this)">
```

Ahora, si lo que deseas es usar el selector a toda costa entonces hazlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var selector = "<?php echo $row['identificacion']?>" + 1;
document.getElementById(selector);
```

Comment: Muy buena tu respuesta, si me funciona, pero para el efecto que necesito si es necesario utilizar el getElementById y un getelementsByClassName, no se si esto sea posible o tena algun error de comillas

Comment: @NestorBautista que efecto quieres lograr? cualquier efecto que quieras hacer con un selector lo puedes hacer con this

Comment: @NestorBautista de igual forma te he editado la respuesta, prueba si te funciona así

Comment: ¿Qué esto `"<?php echo $row['identificacion']; ?>"` no sería un simple string para JS? Lo que yo percibo es que quiere ejecutar código php en una función JS, lo cual hasta donde yo se no se puede, todo lo que tiene que hacer es dentro de la función mandar llamar `event.target` y así obtiene el input

Comment: @Yikarus hasta donde yo se en js se pueden imprimir variables de php yo lo he hecho, aunque lo he hecho en variables no en métodos, para asegurarnos mejor lo indicamos como variable

Comment: Gracias, aunque no me dio la solucion al caso, me ayudo con otra parte que tenia pendiente :)